# Error with non-standard identifier in \copy command

Tags: postgresql, psql, copy, quoted-identifier

Would like to be able to add characters like '-' in the schema name when running `COPY` command in PostgreSQL. Any way to get around this?

```sh
psql -d postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM test-schema.tableName) TO data.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV"
```

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"`enter code here`
> LINE 1: COPY  ( SELECT * FROM test-schema.tableName ) TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',...
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is with the [illegal identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) for schema and table name, and not immediately related to [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) (nor to the [psql meta-command `\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY), which you actually use). Use double-quotes:

```
"test-schema"."tableName"
```

(Assuming you registered the table as `"tableName"`, not as `tablename`, which would be preferable.)
Since you double-quote the command argument in the shell, too, you need to escape the added double-quotes:

```sh
psql -d postgres -c "\copy (SELECT * FROM \"test-schema\".\"tableName\") TO data.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV;"
```

Or use single-quotes in the shell and dollar-quotes for the string:

```sh
psql -d postgres -c '\copy (SELECT * FROM "test-schema"."tableName") TO data.csv DELIMITER $$,$$ CSV;'
```

You wouldn't encounter any of these problems with legal, lower-case identifiers, which do not require double-quoting. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)
- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860)
- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/939860)